# select checked radio button value along with other inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select all the input values from a form including values of checked radio button(s), buttons using the code below:

```
$("form#second :input:not(:button)").each(function () {
        values += $(this).val() + "\n";
});
console.log(values);
```

I know I can get checked radio button values using something like this:

```
$("form#second :input[name=radioBtn]:checked)
```

Is there a way I can combine both of them? Get all input including value of checked radio button

```
<form id="second">
<select>
    <option value="val">Value</option>
</select> 
    <input type="button" value="Del" >
    <button id="btnAdd" class="button" type="submit" >Add</button>
    <textarea id="csTopic" name="comment">Some value</textarea>
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="radioBtn" value="yes">
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="radioBtn" checked value="no">
</form>
```

Comment: can you provide your form code !!

Comment: @DavidJorHpan HTML added

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a really helpful function to use in such cases - [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/55xnJ/2/

```
//Just type
$("#preview_form").serialize();

//to get result:
single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1
```

As you see above, all the elements in the form with `name` attribute will be automatically added into a string with `&` delimiters.

> **Note:** No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned , *get all input including value of checked radio button* . Loop that form all input by `formId input` and use `each` for loop all input ! And then you can check as you require ,below is my example ...

```js
var val = [];
$("#second input").each(function() {
    switch($(this).attr("type")) {
      //radio type
      case "radio" :
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          val.push($(this).val());
      }
      break;
      //other type is set default
      default : 
          val.push($(this).val());
      break;
      }
});
console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="second">
<select>
    <option value="val">Value</option>
</select> 
    <input type="button" value="Del" >
    <button id="btnAdd" class="button" type="submit" >Add</button>
    <textarea id="csTopic" name="comment">Some value</textarea>
    <input type="radio" id="yes" name="radioBtn" value="yes">
    <input type="radio" id="no" name="radioBtn" checked value="no">
</form>
```